# Why can't an SGID program read a file from the same group if it's used by another user?

Tags: permissions

[image]

The "wall" command has SGID for the tty group. The proba file has the tty group. The FS that has the wall binary has no SGID mount option. I thought the wall command would just output the proba's content.

Why can't I access the "proba" file with the "wall" command?

I'm not interested in the wall command itself, it is for the method that I described.

Example for this (altough the file was not directly read): http://blog.silentsignal.eu/2014/06/25/hp-ux-0day-local-privilege-escalation/

Comment: Maybe you could trace `wall` e.g. with `ktrace` to see what is it actually doing that fails.

Answer (score 2):

Programs that run set-uid or set-gid should, and normally do, switch back to the original uid/gid when they're opening files named by the user. They only use the privileges of their set-[ug]id permissions to access the special files that they need for their operation; for instance, `wall` only uses it so that it can open the recipient's terminal. Using the special privileges when opening user files would be a security violation, since it would allow you to access files you shouldn't normally have access to.

Comment: this is commonly known as effective user ID vs real user ID